# Correlation between spam and weekdays

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I am trying to check if there is a correlation between **spam emails and weekdays**.

My `dataframe` looks like as follows:

```
  Spam? Day
0   1.0 Saturday
1   1.0 Saturday
3   0.0 Saturday
5   1.0 Saturday
7   0.0 Friday
... ... ...
346 0.0 Friday
348 1.0 Friday
361 0.0 Saturday
383 1.0 Thursday
387 1.0 Friday
```

where 1 means spam and 0 not spam.

I have tried as follows

```
corr = (numpy.corrcoef(df['Spam?'],df['Days']))
```

and I have got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: can you clarify "correlation"?

Comment: @Marat: Pearson correlation. I think I will need to encode weekdays

Comment: weekday is a categorical value, not numeric. You can't use Pearson correlation for this (well, unless you have a strong reason to believe there is a linear dependency)

Comment: thanks Marat. So I will need to encode weekdays column, will I not?

Comment: I don't know - that's exactly my question. What kind of result do you want to see here?

Comment: a relationship that can show if spam email are more likely spread on Saturday (for instance)

Comment: a common approach is to calculate a chance of getting Saturday's statistics by chance, given all other days. You can calculate difference between means of spam rate, effect size, or distance between distributions. Any of these will be a reasonable start; what's important is to take randomness into account

Comment: To see whether spam is unusually higher or lower on a particular day, you need a categorical metric.  Correlation coefficient is for data with a continuous relationship, such as noting a trend of increasing spam through the week.  Instead, try a chi-squared test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with categorical features/labels. It's not really meaningful to look at correlation.

Instead, you should just look at histograms:

```
pd.crosstab(df['day'], df['spam']).plot.bar()
```

and get something like this:

[image]

The above would give you the **absolute** count for each spam/day combination. You can also visualize the **relative** count with `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('day')['spam'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack('spam').plot.bar()
```

and you get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for you suggestion, Quang Hoang. Really appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a categorical and a categorical variable, Cramer's V is the ideal metric you should use -

```
import scipy.stats as ss
def cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_matrix):
    """ calculate Cramers V statistic for categorical-categorical association.
        uses correction from Bergsma and Wicher, 
        Journal of the Korean Statistical Society 42 (2013): 323-328
    """
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.sum().sum()
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))    
    rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))
cramers_corrected_stat(pd.crosstab(df['Spam?'], df['Day']))
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the weekdays into a number from 0 to 6 and then run `numpy.corrcoef`

Comment: that's the obvious wrong solution, assuming linear dependency between weekdays and spam rate

Comment: yet, this is the question asked - whether there is or there is not a linear dependency.